# Dataframe object in conversion from xlsx to JSON

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I´m new to programming in Python and I´m trying to code a program that reads a xlxs file and converts it to json. (I´ve been using Python 3 and Jupyter Notebook for it, but I've had some problems and difficulties with it.)

===========================

**There are two rows with four columns each in my xlsx file:**

```
id     label        id_customer     label_customer

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil

92    Hong Hong      CUST-88888         China
```

===========================

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

file_imported = pd.read_excel('testing.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Plan1')

list1 = []
list  = []
for index, row in file_imported.iterrows():
    list.append ({
            "id"       : int(row['id']),
            "label"    : str(row['label']),
            "Customer" : list1
            })

    list1.append ({
           "id"       : str(row['id_customer']) ,
           "label"    : str(row['label_customer'])
           })

print (list)

with open ('testing.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list, f, indent= True)
```

========================

**Json Output:**

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil"
   },
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil"
   },
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

========================

**What is expected:**

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

========================

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran a few tests with you code, and I think your issue with only getting a singular row of values may be due to issues with input for your code. I've ran this using your data as a .csv input, and it seems to have output things differently than it's showing on your end. I'm unsure what versions of pandas you're using, but I'd recommend running some tests with your `file_imported` to confirm that it has the correct values. I used `file_imported = pd.read_csv('import.csv')` for this.

I've also found some other related issues you may run into after. When the input is good, this is the output I'm getting:

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "S\u00e3o Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil"
   },
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil"
   },
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

The fix for this is simple, just adding `[index]` to the end of the `"Customer" : list1` reference, like so: `"Customer" : list1[index]. With those two changes, this is the output you should be getting!

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "S\u00e3o Paulo",
  "Customer": {
   "id": "CUST-99992",
   "label": "Brazil"
  }
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": {
   "id": "CUST-88888",
   "label": "China"
  }
 }
]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I upgraded my pandas and now I'm using 0.23.0 version!! I checked out and the output that I mentioned was get because I wrongly added 'list' and 'list1' inside 'for' loop (I already fixed it). Can I add '[index]' to the end of the  "Customer" : list1 ? list1 is a list and should begin with '[' and not '{' ..

Comment: Absolutely! That's exactly what should fix this, since you only want to reference a specific value of list1 from each iteration. Within the loop, list should reference list 1 like so:
`"Customer" : list1[index]`

Answer (score 0):

try to append list1 before you add it in list

```
import pandas as pd
import json

file_imported = pd.read_excel('testing.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Plan1')

list1 = []
list  = []
for index, row in file_imported.iterrows():
    list1.append ({
           "id"       : str(row['id_customer']) ,
           "label"    : str(row['label_customer'])
           })
    list.append ({
            "id"       : int(row['id']),
            "label"    : str(row['label']),
            "Customer" : list1
            })



    print (list)

with open ('testing.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(list, f, indent= True)
```

Comment: I tried to append list1 first, but doesn't worked... I edited my question.. I hope that help to understand the problem better..